python mock library - Replacing original side_effect with an exception fails unexpectedly
I want to use a mock.patch decorator over a class with many test with a default side_effect, and then in some specific tests replace that side_effect with some other behavior. When I try to replace the side_effect with an Exception, the mock code raises TypeError: 'Exception' object is not iterable.
Notice that this only happens when using autospec=True in the decorator. When removed, or replaced with spec=my_original_function, everything works as expected.
Is this a bug on the mock module? I am using version '1.1.0'
Here is how to reproduce the issue.
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch


def my_original_function():
    return 'my_original_function'


def my_default_side_effect():
    return 'my_default_side_effect'



@patch('tests.my_test.my_original_function', side_effect=my_default_side_effect, autospec=True)
class DebugTest(TestCase):
    def test_default_side_effect_works(self, my_patch):  # This works
        self.assertEqual(my_patch(), 'my_default_side_effect')

    def test_default_side_effect_can_be_replaced_with_new_function(self, my_patch):  # This works
        my_patch.side_effect = lambda: 'some_other_side_effect'
        self.assertEqual(my_patch(), 'some_other_side_effect')

    def test_default_side_effect_can_be_replaced_with_new_list(self, my_patch):  # This works
        my_patch.side_effect = ['other_side_effect_1', 'other_side_effect_2']
        self.assertEqual(my_patch(), 'other_side_effect_1')
        self.assertEqual(my_patch(), 'other_side_effect_2')

    def test_default_side_effect_can_be_replaced_with_new_exception(self, my_patch):  # This fails
        my_patch.side_effect = Exception('exception_side_effect')
        with self.assertRaisesRegex(Exception, 'exception_side_effect'):
            my_patch()
            # AssertionError: "exception_side_effect" does not match "'Exception' object is not iterable"


On my system your tests are executed all with success. However try to substitute my_patch.side_effect = Exception('exception_side_effect') with my_patch.side_effect = [Exception('exception_side_effect')]!

I'm not sure why autospec=true causes an error, but there is a way to work around that. Just use raise_exception instead, or try tinkering with a custom object. Here's an example:
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

def my_original_function():
    return 'my_original_function'

def my_default_side_effect():
    return 'my_default_side_effect'

def raise_exception(*args, **kwargs):
    raise Exception('exception_side_effect')

@patch('tests.my_test.my_original_function', side_effect=my_default_side_effect, autospec=True)
class DebugTest(TestCase):
    def test_default_side_effect_works(self, my_patch): 
        self.assertEqual(my_patch(), 'my_default_side_effect')

    def test_default_side_effect_can_be_replaced_with_new_function(self, my_patch):  
        my_patch.side_effect = lambda: 'some_other_side_effect'
        self.assertEqual(my_patch(), 'some_other_side_effect')

    def test_default_side_effect_can_be_replaced_with_new_list(self, my_patch):  
        my_patch.side_effect = ['other_side_effect_1', 'other_side_effect_2']
        self.assertEqual(my_patch(), 'other_side_effect_1')
        self.assertEqual(my_patch(), 'other_side_effect_2')

    def test_default_side_effect_can_be_replaced_with_new_exception(self, my_patch):  
        my_patch.side_effect = raise_exception
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as cm:
            my_patch()
        self.assertEqual(str(cm.exception), 'exception_side_effect')

